# Python Skype4Py Windows 7 Installation

Tags: python-2.7

Installed python 2.7 
In command line, tried to install SkypePy4;

```
c:\Python27>pip install Skype4Py
```

got error:

> Collecting Skype4Py
>     Using cached Skype4Py-1.0.35.zip
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\SNICHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-oaotil6i  \Skype4Py\setup.py", line 111
>           print 'zipping the documentation'
>                                           ^
>       SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>
> No folder pip-build-oaotil6i is seen in Temp folder.
>   Security and hidden constarints are also checked

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems with the Skype4Py-package itselve - solving:

1. download the package from the [pypi-website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Skype4Py/) as zip.
2. unzip somewhere and change the following files:

   1. setup.py: (line 111) `#` in front of the line or `(`, `)` around the string
   2. README.rst: (line 203) remove the " “S” " (if you get a UnicodeDecodeError)
3. install with: `pip install "C:\path\to\unzipped\and\edited\dir"`